# gxx personality not found CODEBLOCKS

Tags: qt, mingw, codeblocks, libstdc++

While trying to run `c++` programs with MINGW & CODEBLOCKS I am getting the following error

```
The procedure entry point `_gxx_persopnality _v0` could not be located in the dynamic link library `libstdcc++-6.dll`
```

[image: http://i50.tinypic.com/256wgfd.png]

This is a picture of the current setting I am using. I am using `G++` and NOT gcc

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/2z8cg8n.png]

Note :

1. I have set the path of MINGW in my path(environment variables)
2. Getting this error since i downloaded QT SDK which comes with its own Mingw
3. Reinstalled both Codeblocks and MINGW several times.
4. Both my path and system variables are set to point to my installation location of MinGW's bin directory.

How do I resolve this error? I want to use both codeblocks and qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've added Qt's own MinGW into the `PATH` too. The priority is given to the one which is the first one encountered in the `PATH`. Therefore, you seem to have added Qt's MinGW before your original stand-alone MinGW distribution in `PATH`.

You seem to have compiled your application with your original MinGW distribution, then you've installed Qt's one and because of it your application is now loading the wrong `libstdcc++-6.dll` (i.e. the one from Qt's MinGW) while it should load the one from your original MinGW distribution.

You should choose which one you want to use for the development, because they have different versions and therefore their dynamic libraries (like `libstdcc++-6.dll`) have different layout.

So if you simply want your application to run properly now - just put the original MinGW in `PATH` before Qt's one.

If you want to start development with Qt (what I suspect is true since you've downloaded it), then you have 2 options to decide on:

1. You want to stay with your original MinGW distribution and build Qt
   applications with it too, rather than with Qt's built in one. For
   instance, I do like that, i.e. I never use Qt's built in MinGW
   because it is very outdated and doesn't support 64-bit Windows
   targets. To do that you'd have to build Qt itself from source using
   your original MinGW distribution.
2. You don't care (or too lazy to build Qt from source), then you'd
   better use the Qt's built in MinGW for your development in general
   and possibly remove the original MinGW distribution at all.

**NOTE:** What I was trying to emphasize is that you cannot mix these 2 MinGW distributions. Well, that's not actually true, of course you can if you know when exactly you can do it and how, but that requires in-depth knowledge of linkage process and numerous pitfalls associated with it, which I suppose you don't have, yet (sorry if I'm wrong). However, even then you are not 100% safe and still can experience weird bugs and crashes. That's why, to avoid these headaches, just don't mix them.

Comment: Ok I corrected the path and everything was fine. Today I installed Visual Studio 2012 (Needed OpenGl glut libraries for my college project). And now I am facing the same problem again. 

I made sure that both the path variables and system variables first and foremost redirect to c:/mingw/bin directories. I have also checked that c:/mingw/bin does contain the libstdc++ dll file. Now what do I do? Please help!!!!

Comment: You'd have to open another question, and describe in details the new problem. The current question in it's current form is answered, and therefore, trying to ask different questions (i.e. the ones deserving to be opened as a separate question) in comments is not a good idea. As a result, I suggest not to clutter this question and create the new one. I'll look into your new question and try to answer it, just make sure to describe all the details.

Comment: Umm sorry. I didn't want to spam the forum with too many related questions. In other forums I have been told to keep all the questions related to the same topic within one thread.

Comment: I posted a new question like you asked me too. I have reaccepted your answer as an acceptable answer. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149499/gxx-personality-v0-error-with-codeblocks