# _Gxx_Personality_v0 error with Codeblocks

Tags: mingw, codeblocks, libstdc++

While trying to run C++ programs with MINGW & CODEBLOCKS I am getting the following error:

```
The procedure entry point _gxx_persopnality _v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdcc++-6.dll
```

This is a picture of the current setting I am using. I am using `g++` and NOT `gcc`:

[image: Screenshot]

Note:

1. I have added the path of MinGW to `PATH` (environment variables).
2. Getting this error since I downloaded QT SDK & visual studio 2010 which comes with its own Mingw & VC with its own compiler.
3. Reinstalled both Code::blocks and MinGW several times.
4. Both my path and system variables are set to point to my installation location of MinGW's `bin` directory.
5. I am also using Visual Studio 2012.

How do I resolve this error? I want to use all: Code::blocks, Qt, and Visual studio 2012.

Comment: OK, again what did you do since my last answer? I told you to place MinGW `bin` directory to `PATH` before any other toolchain (for example, Qt's built in MinGW). You still didn't provide any screenshot of your `PATH` environment variable. Please, copy-paste the contents of your `PATH` environment variable (not the screenshot). The last screenshot is absolutely irrelevant, so delete it please.

Comment: It is still not clear what do you want to achieve? Do you want to build projects with Visual Studio 2012, or MinGW + Code::blocks, or both?

Comment: I practice my codes in Codeblocks integrated with MinGW. I need Visual Studio for my Graphics Project in College. Well, QT is a framework I want to learn. Hence the need for the three.

contents of my PATH variables

System Variable Path :

`C:\MinGW\bin;E:\Program Files (x86)\JAVA\bin;E:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\;F:\Git\bin;F:\QT\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin;F:\QT\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin;`

User variable Path:

`C:\MingW\bin;e:\Ruby193\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ ;`
Since your last answer I installed VC12

Comment: 1) Why on the screenshot in Code::blocks I see `E:\MinGW` and not `C:\MinGW`? I.e. it does not coincide with your `PATH`. 2) If you want to use OpenGL and GLUT, you don't need Visual Studio, they are both available for MinGW too. Finally, installation of Visual Studio cannot cause the error your getting. Something is wrong with the `PATH` again, i.e. your mixing different MinGW distributions, and it seems like it's because of the item (1), see above. You should be more careful. I suspect that you build with MinGW from drive `E` and run application with `libstdcc++-6.dll` from drive `C`.

Comment: That was an old screenshot. I basically copied it from the previous thread. My path is declared as c: only. Here is an updated screenshot:
`http://i.imgur.com/tEp45ll.png`

I have looked at all the possible scenarios. My only logical conclusion is that the current latest MinGW must have an unstable Libstdc. I think I should probably downgrade to the previous stable releases.

EDIT:Also I removed the installation in E: directory with an uninstaller software. I made sure to leave no traces of the previous installation in the HD or the registries and then removed all e:/mingw reference frm path

Comment: One more thing I'd like to mention, for example, I use MinGW 4.7.2, and in my case the library is called `libstdc++-6.dll`, not `libstdcc++-6.dll`! I don't know from where did you get that kind of distribution. Also, try to rebuild the project and see what happens.

Comment: Even my MingW has a `libstdc++-6.dll` file. I read on some other forum that the MinGW 4.7.2 has an unstable libstdc file and using a `libstdcc++-6.dll` of previous builds solved the same problem. So I tried it but it didn't help. Now I have restored the original dll. I guess I will try reinstalling MingW and see what happens.

P.S: I downloaded minGW from the official website.

Comment: I suggest [MinGW Builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/).

Comment: Using MinGW builds solved the problem. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Good, want me to post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of Visual Studio alone can in no way cause errors like that. Something is still wrong with your MinGW distribution. What I find suspicious is the name of the library `libstdcc++-6.dll`. For instance, in my MinGW-w64 based on GCC 4.7.2 the library is named `libstdc++-6.dll`, and that's the correct name, it was there for years.

What I can suggest is to look into some other MinGW distribution. For example, you could have tried **[MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/download.php#mingw-builds)**. It already offers the bleeding-edge GCC 4.8.0. What's more it offers all the possible variations:

- 64-bit targets;
- 32-bit targets;
- Win32 threads;
- POSIX threads;
- SEH exceptions;
- DWARF exceptions;
- SJLJ exceptions.

so your choice is quite flexible. To learn more about all these variations (as this is very important stuff to know) I encourage you to take a look at **[this article](http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit)**.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try copying libstdc++-6.dll from your MinGW\bin into mingw\bin inside codeblocks folder and replace the one that exists in there. It worked for me.